# Visual Studio 2013 só abre projetos 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

Sempre que vou criar um novo projeto no VS2013, não tenho opção de projetos, apenas a opção: `WEB >> Visual Studio 2012`. Aí sim, tenho várias opções de projetos como MVC 3 e 4 e assim vai. Como eu atualizo? Tentei pelo NuGet, mas continua a mesma coisa

Answer (score 1):

O **Visual Studio 2013** não fornece acesso a alguns *templates* que estavam disponíveis no **Visual Studio 2012**. Se você quiser usar um desses *templates*, você pode clicar em Visual Studio 2012.

Veja [nesse link](http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/creating-web-projects-in-visual-studio).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: @pnet Conseguiu resolver? A resposta foi útil?

Answer (score 1):

No Visual Studio 2013, o ASP.NET só usa MVC5, portanto só tem uma opção:

[image: Novo Projeto]
[image: MVC]

Na opção de Visual Studio 2012, há ainda a compatibilidade retroativa para MVC4, no máximo.

[image: Visual Studio 2012]